# marginalisation with conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

In this link, Marginalization with conditional probability is answered.

[Conditional probability with chain rule and marginalisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401631/conditional-probability-with-chain-rule-and-marginalisation)

I am little bit confused about my another way of thinking and would like to understand what is the wrong.

we can marginalize a conditional probability like this $p(p|b) = \sum_{m'} P(p,m'|b) $

However, If I think in the way like below
$$P(p|b)=\frac{P(p, b)}{P(b)}$$

Let's marginalize the above equation

$$P(p|b)=\frac{P(p, b)}{P(b)} =  \sum_{m'} \left(  \frac{P(p, b,m' )}{P(b , m')}\right)$$

Because $P(b) = \sum_{m'} P(b , m')$ and

$ P(p, b ) = \sum_{m'} P(p,b , m' )$

Why this way of thinking is wrong?

Why is the correct equation the following one; ( there is no $m$ in the denumerator)

$$P(p|b)=\frac{P(p, b)}{P(b)} =  \sum_{m'} \left(  \frac{P(p, b , m' )}{P(b)}\right)$$

Thank you

Comment: show your complete work when going from $\frac{p(p\cap b)}{p(b)}$ to the next equation. You are treating division as additive, it is not.

Comment: @Xi'an, Thanks I corrected them.

Comment: @JohnMadden, I didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: @erdisayar start with the show your work part, and we can help with the rest :)

Comment: I already showed it above ?
Normally, the following equation is the marginalization rule for the conditional probability
$p(p|b) = \sum_{m'} P(p,m'|b)  = \sum_{m'} \left(  \frac{P(p, b , m' )}{P(b)}\right) $

The rule comes from the total law of probabilty.

$P(B) = \sum_{i} P(A_i)P(B|A_i)$

If I express the conditional probability like this  $$P(p|b)=\frac{P(p, b)}{P(b)}$$
and marginalize both numerator and denumerator using Total law of probability.

$P(b) = \sum_{m'} P(b , m')$ and 

$ P(p, b ) = \sum_{m'} P(p,b , m' )$

Comment: And put them in the equation, I am getting this following final result. However, It is wrong!

 $$P(p|b)=\frac{P(p, b)}{P(b)} =  \sum_{m'} \left(  \frac{P(p, b,m' )}{P(b , m')}\right)$$

The correct answer is the following one; That means there is no marginalization in the denumerator part which is the point I didn't understand why It is not considered 

 $$P(p|b)=\frac{P(p, b)}{P(b)} =  \sum_{m'} \left(  \frac{P(p, b , m' )}{P(b)}\right)$$

Comment: @JohnMadden, Could I explain the problem?